# Do algebraic datatypes in Haskell equal discriminated unions in F#?

Tags: haskell, f#, functional-programming, algebraic-data-types, discriminated-union

I am learning Haskell and would like to know whether the constructs known in Haskell as algebraic datatypes are the same that discriminated unions in F# or there are some subtle differences between them.

I would also appreciate much a good comparison between F# (my first functional language) and other functional languages, especially as regards similar concepts but with substantial but important differences.

Comment: Might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961/what-are-the-primary-differences-between-haskell-and-f

Comment: In response to your second question, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159356/why-is-f-so-special/159414#159414) lists some F# distinctives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(I come from OCaml, but I looked over the relevant F# stuff and it seems the same. Correct me if I'm wrong.) They are the same, just different terminology for the same thing, but there are a few syntactical differences. For example, to define a constructor with multiple data elements, in OCaml and F# you write the type as if they were stuffed in a tuple:

Haskell:

```
data Whatever = Foo TypeA TypeB
```

OCaml / F#:

```
type whatever = Foo of typeA * typeB
```

Similarly, to pattern match on it, you similarly act like a single argument that is a tuple with all the data members stuffed inside:

Haskell:

```
case x of Foo a b -> ...
```

OCaml / F#:

```
match x with Foo (a, b) -> ...
```

Edit: apparently the following does not apply in F#

<s>Also, in Haskell the constructor automatically becomes a function that you can use by itself like any other value:</s>

```
zipWith Foo xs ys
```

OCaml/F# don't do this. You could manually define your own functions for each constructor.

Comment: Case identifiers/constructors are first-class functions in F# too: `List.zip [1;2;3] ['a';'b';'c'] |> List.map Foo`

Comment: F# is an ML variant, so you're correct that it's very similar to O'Caml.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not very familiar with Haskell (I've only read [*Learn You a Haskell*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)) but I haven't yet come across a basic difference between DUs and Haskell's algebraic data types--they're both attempts to model the same concept. Having said that, F# and Haskell have very different type systems (e.g., Haskell has type classes/higher-kinded types; F# is deeply grounded in OOP, etc.) so there is asymmetry, but nothing limited to these data types.